# I suspect that some person acts as "Community" user

Tags: support, duplicates, community-user

It is supposed that "Community" is an automated service.

But a couple of times it made some human decisions.

Like [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/649559/bluetooth-does-not-detect-any-devices-dell-inspiron-15-12-04lts).

I voted to close as duplicate. But as soon as the issue was fixed, "Community"  closed it.

Was it done by a human?

Comment: See: [When does the Community ♦ moderator vote to close a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228455/when-does-the-community-%E2%99%A6-moderator-vote-to-close-a-question)

Comment: @Seth That answer does not look related. That is related to a case where some user deleted an account. Here there it is a new question and I did not delete my account yet :-)

Comment: It looks like OP closed his question. It is explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. See the "UPDATED" section in the answer I linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote.]

When you voted to close the question, the system asked its author a question similar to this:

[image]

The author conceded that the linked question you provided *did indeed* solve his problem. The system - represented by [the Community user](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1) - reacted to this by closing the question.

This is generally a much more expedient method of handling duplicates where the author is around and responsive.

#### See also: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes)

Comment: I learned something new today! [You *really think* you know what you are doing!](http://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=accounts)  **;-)**